# Programmatically change UISwitch state ON or OFF

Tags: ios, uiswitch

There is a `UISwitch` which set itself ON or OFF based on if the Push Notifications are enabled or not. I've searched and implemented as it is said on other questions on stackoverflow in my `viewDidLoad` method as:

```
SettingsTableViewCell *cell = [[SettingsTableViewCell alloc] init];

    if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]) {
        [cell.mainSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell.mainSwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
    }
```

Now it is going into the right condition but it is not changing the state of the switch. I don't want it to get tapped and then change the state. It should check if notifications are enabled then set on otherwise stay off.

Comment: Under which method are you writing this code?

Comment: Can you add more code? so we can help you better.

Comment: where this code is written? i think there is nothing wrong with switch code but there might be a problem with cell instantiation.

Comment: Yes, Usama is right. The above code is correct and the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: My bad. I've found the error. You are right the error was some place else. Thanks @Usama

Comment: if SettingsTableViewCell is a subclass of UITableViewCell then the above code shouldn't be in viewDidLoad